# Copying a portion of an image and translating it to the same position on new image in Pixlr

Tags: selections, pixlr

I'm new to using Pixlr so I'm wondering if there is a way that I can select a portion of an image using the wand tool and then copy it to a new blank image (which has the same dimensions as the original) so that the copied portion is placed in the exact same spot in the new image as it's located in the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Once the desired portion has been selected with the wand tool, you click and drag that selected portion to the blank image and it sets it in the exact spot as it is in the original image :]

Comment: Could you mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem? Otherwise it shows up in the feed and list of unanswered question. Thanks